# Adding additional functionality to a basic movement tracking script in Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

For my dissertation project I am looking at tadpole movement patterns. I have a python script written by a previous PhD student. Currently the script takes a video and tracks the tadpole as it swims around the tank, at the end it outputs a text file with the total distance travelled in pixles. At the start of the script I get prompted with a window to designate the tracking arena.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcyva.jpg). To designate the tracking area I can drag around a square to the place I want. The draggable square has a numbered grid inside it. Then I get another window to draw a square around an indiviudal tadpole which is used to set the minimum and maximum size that the script detects when tracking the movement.

For my dissertation I need to modify the script to track distance travelled within the outside 16 squares (The numbered squares which are seen when designating the tracking arena) and the distance travelled within the middle 9 squares.

The whole script is split into 2 files, one which I run using command line and the other contains some of the needed functions.

This is the main code which I run.

```
#Importing all the packages needed and the tracking functions
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import Tracking_functions1 as tc


# Information to change
sub_varThreshold = 90 #values usually work between 90-150 - the pixel threshold value to be counted as a "moving tadpole" object
sub_learn_rate = -1 # -1 is the default, 0.05 also works well
blur_kernal = (1, 1) #use smaller kernal sizes (1,1) for small tadpoles and larger kernals (5,5) for big tadpoles
min_area = 1 #initalise min area as a number before setting by drawing a rectangle
max_area = 1 #initalise max area as a number before setting by drawing a rectangle
large_movement_threshold = 1 #initalise threshold as a number before setting by drawing a rectangle
start_position = 2 #where we start
start_frame = start_position  #the videos are fps so if start position is in seconds, this takes us to frames
min_area_multiplier = 0.3 #the min area we will track will be 0.4 of the rectangle drawn around the individual
max_area_multiplier = 1.5 #the max area we will track will be 0.4 of the rectangle drawn around the individual
key = None #initalise 
cap = None #initalise
frame_count = 0  # Variable to keep track of the frame number


# Global variables for tracking arena dimensions
arena_width = 900
arena_height = 900
grid_rows = 5
grid_cols = 5
grid_width = arena_width // grid_cols
grid_height = arena_height // grid_rows


# Create dictionaries to store window statuses
windows = {
    'Draw Tracking Arena': False,
    'Draw Area to Track': False
}

# Create a function to create and show windows
def create_window(window_name, image):
    cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
    windows[window_name] = True

# Create a function to destroy windows
def destroy_window(window_name):
    cv2.destroyWindow(window_name)
    windows[window_name] = False

# Function to handle mouse events for dragging the square
def drag_square(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global top_left_pt1, dragging, offset_x, offset_y, bottom_right_pt1, arena_width, arena_height

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if top_left_pt1[0] <= x <= bottom_right_pt1[0] and top_left_pt1[1] <= y <= bottom_right_pt1[1]:
            dragging = True
            offset_x = x - top_left_pt1[0]
            offset_y = y - top_left_pt1[1]
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if dragging:
            new_top_left_x = x - offset_x
            new_top_left_y = y - offset_y
            bottom_right_pt1 = (new_top_left_x + arena_width, new_top_left_y + arena_height)
            top_left_pt1 = (bottom_right_pt1[0] - arena_width, bottom_right_pt1[1] - arena_height)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        dragging = False

# Function to calculate grid points
def calculate_grid_points():
    grid_points = []
    for i in range(grid_rows):
        for j in range(grid_cols):
            x = j * grid_width
            y = i * grid_height
            grid_points.append((x, y))
    return grid_points

# Function to draw grid lines on the tracking arena
def draw_grid(image):
    for i in range(1, grid_rows):
        cv2.line(image, (0, i * grid_height), (arena_width, i * grid_height), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    for j in range(1, grid_cols):
        cv2.line(image, (j * grid_width, 0), (j * grid_width, arena_height), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    return image


# Function to draw the draggable square with grid and labels on the tracking arena window
def draw_tracking_arena_with_grid(image, top_left_pt1):
    # Draw grid lines on the image and label each square
    for i in range(grid_rows):
        for j in range(grid_cols):
            x1 = top_left_pt1[0] + j * grid_width
            y1 = top_left_pt1[1] + i * grid_height
            x2 = top_left_pt1[0] + (j + 1) * grid_width
            y2 = top_left_pt1[1] + (i + 1) * grid_height
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 2)
            square_number = i * grid_cols + j + 1
            cv2.putText(image, str(square_number), (x1 + 10, y1 + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # Draw the draggable square
    cv2.rectangle(image, top_left_pt1, bottom_right_pt1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw a green rectangle

    return image


# Create one numpy arrays to place over images, I am creating ROI here because I seem to need to do that to clear ROI between batches
img = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), np.uint8)
ROI = np.zeros_like(img)

# Open and read the txt file of video names
myfile = open('G:/Aug1/A1/video_info.txt', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
myfile = myfile.readlines()
batch_numbers = set()
 

for line in myfile[1:]:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()
    BatchID = 0
    TadpoleID = 1
    TrialID = 2
    columnvid = 3
    LR = 4
    batch_numbers.add(line[BatchID])

for batch in batch_numbers:
    ROI.fill(0) #clearing ROI between batches
    print("Is ROI cleared:", np.count_nonzero(ROI) == 0)
    print("ROI dimensions (width, height):", ROI.shape)
    

    top_left_pt1 = (0, 0) #resetting tracking area and arena
    bottom_right_pt1 = (arena_width, arena_height)
    top_left_pt2 = (0, 0)
    bottom_right_pt2 = (0, 0)
        

   

    for line in myfile[1:]:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        BatchID = 0
        if line[BatchID] != batch:
         continue
        TadpoleID = 1
        TrialID = 2
        columnvid = 3
        LR = 4
        Behav = 5
        vidx = (line[columnvid])

           # Create a unique window name for each tadpole based on TadpoleID
        tracking_window_name = f'Tracking Arena for Individual {line[TadpoleID]} on the {line[LR]} {line[Behav]}'
        area_window_name = f'Area of Individual {line[TadpoleID]} to Track on the {line[LR]}  {line[Behav]}'
        results_fn = ('_'.join(('Track_Results/Batch', batch, 'Individial', line[TadpoleID], 'Trial', line[TrialID], 'Behav', line[Behav], line[LR])))
   
        suffix = '.txt'
        results_txt = os.path.join(results_fn + suffix)
        myresults = open(results_txt, 'a')
        printheader = print('TadpoleID', 'TrialID', 'FrameNo', 'Xcentroid', 'Ycentroid', 'DistX', 'DistY', 'PixelDist', 'CumulPixelDistTrvalled', 'CumulPixelDistInculded', 'InculsionStatus', sep='\t', file=myresults)
        myresults.close()
        myresults = open(results_txt, 'a')

        # Capture the first frame of the video 
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidx)

        ret, first_frame = cap.read()
        
        if not ret:
          print("Error: Failed to read the first frame")
          break
 

          # Create a window to display the tracking arena
        cv2.namedWindow(tracking_window_name)
        cv2.setMouseCallback(tracking_window_name, drag_square)

        while True:
            square_image1 = first_frame.copy()
            overlay = draw_tracking_arena_with_grid(square_image1, top_left_pt1)
            cv2.imshow(tracking_window_name, overlay)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

            if key == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

 
        square_image1 = first_frame.copy()
        draw_tracking_arena_with_grid(square_image1, top_left_pt1)
        print("Window 'Draw Tracking Arena' opened.")

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidx)

        # Skip the first 49 frames to reach the 50th frame
        for i in range(49):
         ret, _ = cap.read()
         if not ret:
          print("Error: Failed to read frame ", i)
          break

# Read the 50th frame for square_image2
        ret, square_image2 = cap.read()
        if not ret:
         print("Error: Failed to read the 50th frame for square_image2")
         break
        
        create_window(area_window_name, square_image2)
        print("Window 'Draw Area' opened.")

        def draw_square2(event, x, y, flags, param):
            global square_image2, drawing2, top_left_pt2, bottom_right_pt2
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                drawing2 = True
                top_left_pt2 = (x, y)
            elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                drawing2 = False
                bottom_right_pt2 = (x, y)
                cv2.rectangle(square_image2, top_left_pt2, bottom_right_pt2, (255, 255, 255), -1)

        drawing2 = False
        cv2.setMouseCallback(area_window_name, draw_square2)
        def check_for_keys():
          key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
          return key
        
        while True:
            cv2.imshow(area_window_name, square_image2)
        
            key = check_for_keys()

            if key == ord('q'):
                break
           


            if top_left_pt1[0] < bottom_right_pt1[0] and top_left_pt1[1] < bottom_right_pt1[1]:
                ROI = cv2.rectangle(img, top_left_pt1, bottom_right_pt1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
            
            
           
                
            
            if top_left_pt2[0] < bottom_right_pt2[0] and top_left_pt2[1] < bottom_right_pt2[1]:
                drawn_area = abs(bottom_right_pt2[0] - top_left_pt2[0]) * abs(bottom_right_pt2[1] - top_left_pt2[1])
                width = abs(bottom_right_pt2[0] - top_left_pt2[0])
                height = abs(bottom_right_pt2[1] - top_left_pt2[1])
                longest_side_length = max(width, height)
                
                min_area = drawn_area * min_area_multiplier
                max_area = drawn_area * max_area_multiplier
                large_movement_threshold = 3.5 * longest_side_length
                print(large_movement_threshold)
            
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

        prev_x = deque(maxlen=1)
        prev_y = deque(maxlen=1)
        prev_xy = deque(maxlen=1)
        prev_x.append(0)
        prev_y.append(0)
        prev_xy.append(None)

        pts = deque(maxlen=100)
        cxpts = deque(maxlen=2)
        cypts = deque(maxlen=2)
        dist_travelled = deque()

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidx)
        fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        cap.set(1, 1)
        end_frame = int(700 * fps)
        framecount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        sub_history = 100
        subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=sub_history, varThreshold=sub_varThreshold, detectShadows=False)

        while True:
            frame = cap.read()
            frame = frame[1]
            frame_pos = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)

            if frame_pos > end_frame:
                myresults.close()
                break
            if frame is None:
                myresults.close()
                break

            frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, ROI)
            
            mask, blur, eq = tc.create_mask(frame, subtractor, sub_learn_rate, blur_kernal)
            c, cx, cy, cxcy = tc.detect_contours(frame, blur, mask, eq, min_area, max_area, prev_x, prev_y, prev_xy)
            print(cx,  cy)
            ix, iy, Pixel_dist, cumul_dist_travelled, cumul_dist_included, inclusion_status = tc.calculate_distance(cx, cy, cxpts, cypts, dist_travelled, large_movement_threshold)

           
                
            pts = tc.draw_lines(cxcy, pts, frame, blur, mask)

            printresults = print(line[TadpoleID], line[TrialID], int(frame_pos), cx, cy, ix, iy, Pixel_dist, cumul_dist_travelled, cumul_dist_included, inclusion_status, sep='\t', file=myresults) #print results to file

           

            
            frame, blur, mask, eq = tc.HUD_info(frame, blur, mask, eq, line, TadpoleID, frame_pos, cumul_dist_travelled, inclusion_status)

            output = tc.output(frame, mask, blur, eq, mode="frame+new_mask")

            key = tc.frame_display_time(fps, mode="veryfast_speed")

            cv2.imshow('tadpole_tracker', frame)
           
           

        

            if key == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

        

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
myresults.close()
```

This is the code containing some functions which are called over in the main script.

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
import math


def create_mask(frame, subtractor, sub_learn_rate, blur_kernal):
    """
    This function retrieves a video frame and preprocesses it for 
    object tracking. 
    The code converts the image to greyscale (gray, eq), blurs the image (blur) to reduce noise and returns 
    a thresholded image (mask) which is determined by a min and max threshold values (minthresh and maxthresh).
    The mask is dilated to remove small spots appearing in the mask. 

    Parameters.
    ----------
    frame: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 3)
        source image with 3 colour channels
    subtractor: cv2 function
        the type of subtractor used to create mask
    sub_learn_rate: float
        how many previous frames are used to estimate tadpole's next position
    blur_kernal: 
        array, int
        how many pixels are combined to create the blurred image
    """
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    eq = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, blur_kernal, 0)
    mask = subtractor.apply(blur, learningRate=sub_learn_rate)
    minthresh = 60 
    maxthresh = 255 
    mask = cv2.threshold(mask, minthresh, maxthresh, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=3) 
    
    return mask, blur, eq

def detect_contours(frame, blur, mask, eq, min_area, max_area, prev_x, prev_y, prev_xy):
    """
    This function detects contours (binary mask images), thresholds them based on area and draws them.

    Parameters
    ----------
    frame: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 3)
        source image with 3 colour channels
    blur: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        blurred image with 1 colour channel
    mask: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        binarised image with 1 colour channel 
    eq: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        source image converted from colour to grey - 1 colour channel
    min_area: int
        the minimum area a contour should be to considered a tadpole and not noise eg specs of food left in tank 
    max_area:
        the minimum area a contour should be to considered a tadpole and not noise eg water ripples
    prev_x: int
        previous x contour coordinate
    prev_y: int
        previous y contour coordinate
    prev_xy: array, int
        previous xy contour coordinate

    """
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #finds the contours (outlines) of the binary mask image
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) #select these contour
    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        extent = area / float(w * h)
        
        if area < min_area or area > max_area:
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, -1)
    mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, mask, mask = mask)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) #finds the contours (outlines) of the binary mask image
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts) #select these contour
    for c in cnts:
        c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[-1] 
        M = cv2.moments(c) #allows calculation of centroid
        if M["m00"] or M["m10"] != 0:
            cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            cxcy = (int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])) 
        else:
            cx = 0
            cy = 0
            cxcy = (0,0)
        if cx == 319 and cy == 179:
            cx = 0
            cy = 0
            cxcy = (319,179)
        prev_x.appendleft(cx)
        prev_y.appendleft(cy)
        prev_xy.appendleft(cxcy)
        (cx, cy, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c) #Define the xy coordinates and width+height of the contour
        for img in (frame, blur, mask, eq):
            cv2.rectangle(img, (cx, cy), (cx + w, cy + h), (0, 255, 0), 1) #define colour and shape of rectangle and place on the frame
    else:
        for x in prev_x:
            cx = x
        for y in prev_y:
            cy = y
        for xy in prev_xy:
            cxcy = xy
        c = None
    return c, cx, cy, cxcy



def calculate_distance(cx, cy, cxpts, cypts, dist_travelled, large_movement_threshold):

    """
    This function calculates the distance the tracked object moves.
    The distance is calculated for consecutive and cumlative distance travelled. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    cx: float
        The objets current location on the x axsis (its x centroid) in current frame
    cy: float
        The objets current location on the y axsis (its y centroid) in current frame
    cxpts: array, float
        A list of all current x centroids from previous frames
    cypts: array, float
        A list of all current y centroids from previous frames
    dist_travelled: float
        distance object has moved from this frame and previous frame

    """
    inclusion_status = "Unknown"  #Give inclusion status a defintion before if block
    #step 1: append xy coordinates to a list
    cxpts.appendleft(cx) #append x coordinates to cxpts list
    cypts.appendleft(cy) #append y coordinates to cxpts list
        
    #step 2: calculate distance between consecutive x and y points 
    #calculate the distance between consecutive x points and call the value ix
    ix = 0 #unless otherwise stated ix = 0
    for ix in range(1, len(cxpts)): #for values in the cxpts list
        if cxpts[ix] == 0 or cxpts[ix-1] == 0: #if the current cx value is a zero, ix = 0
            ix = 0
        else: #otherwise perform the following to calculate ix
            ix = (cxpts[ix]-cxpts[ix-1]) #ix = current cx value - previous cx value
    #calculate distance between consecutive y points
    iy = 0 #unless otherwise stated iy = 0
    for iy in range(1, len(cypts)): #for values in the cypts list
        if cypts[iy] == 0 or cypts[iy-1] == 0: #if the current cy value is a zero, iy = 0
            iy = 0
        else: #otherwise perform the following to calculate iy
            iy = (cypts[iy]-cypts[iy-1]) #iy = current cy value - previous cy value

    #step 3: calculate the distance travelled between consecutive points
    #calculate distance travelled between two points (in pixels)
    #define some values
    square_ix = (ix*ix) 
    square_iy = (iy*iy) 
    #calculate the distance as sqrt of the square_ix + square_iy values
    Pixel_dist = math.sqrt(square_ix+square_iy) 
    #round the value to 2 decimal places
    Pixel_dist = round(Pixel_dist, 2)

    #step 4: calculate cumlative distance travelled (in pixels)
    #append distance travelled calcultions to a list
    dist_travelled.appendleft(Pixel_dist)
    #unless otherwise stated cumlative distance travelled = 0
    cumul_dist_travelled = 0
    cumul_dist_included = 0
    #sum each value found in the dist_travelled list
    for cumul_dist_travelled in range(1, len(dist_travelled)):
        cumul_dist_travelled = sum(dist_travelled) # Update cumulative distance regardless of inclusion status
   
    if Pixel_dist < large_movement_threshold:
       inclusion_status = "Included"
    else:
       inclusion_status = "Excluded"  # Frame distance is too large

     # Calculate cumulative distance for included frames
    if inclusion_status == "Included":
       cumul_dist_included = sum([d for d in dist_travelled if d < large_movement_threshold])
    

    #print(f"Pixel_dist: {Pixel_dist}")
    #print(f"Inclusion Status: {inclusion_status}")
    #print(f"Cumulative Distance Included: {cumul_dist_included}") #removed for now

      


    #round the value to 2 decimal places
    cumul_dist_travelled = round(cumul_dist_travelled, 2)
    cumul_dist_included = round(cumul_dist_included, 2)

    return ix, iy, Pixel_dist, cumul_dist_travelled, cumul_dist_included, inclusion_status

def draw_lines(cxcy, pts, frame, blur, mask):
    """
    This function draws a line between consecutive locations the object moves
     
    Parameters
    ----------
    cxcy: array, float
        The object's current location (its centroid) in the current frame
    pts: int
        The number of previous consecutive locations to draw lines for
    frame: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 3)
        source image with 3 colour channels
    blur: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        blurred image with 1 colour channel
    mask: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        binarised image with 1 colour channel 
    """
    
    if cxcy != (319, 179):
        pts.appendleft(cxcy)
    
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue
        line_thickness = 1
        for img in (frame, blur, mask):
            cv2.line(img, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), line_thickness)  # place centroid lines on frame
            cv2.line(img, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), line_thickness)  # place centroid lines on mask image

    return pts




def HUD_info(frame, blur, mask, eq, line, columnID, frame_pos, cumul_dist_travelled, inclusion_status):
    """
    This function provides the Heads UP Display on the image to show details of the current tadpole being tracked
    Parameters
    ----------
    frame: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 3)
        source image with 3 colour channels
    blur: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        blurred image with 1 colour channel
    mask: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        binarised image with 1 colour channel 
    eq: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        source image converted from colour to grey - 1 colour channel
    line: str
        reads the information in the correct ACT_video_info.txt file
    columnID: str 
        gets tadpole ID from ACT_video_info.txt file under the column name ID
    frame_pos: int
        the current frame number of source image
    cumul_dist_travelled: float
        the total distance travelled object has been recorded to move in pixels
    """
    for img in (frame, blur, mask):
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 225), (110,240), (255,255,255), -1) #rectangle location and colour
        cv2.putText(frame, "TadpoleID: {}".format(line[columnID]), (15, 235), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35 , (0,0,0)) #retrieve frame number from cap and place in rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 250), (110,265), (255,255,255), -1) #rectangle location and colour
        cv2.putText(frame, "Frame No: {}".format(int(frame_pos)), (15, 260), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35 , (0,0,0)) #retrieve frame number from cap and place in rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 275), (135,290), (255,255,255), -1) #rectangle location and colour for frame number
        cv2.putText(frame, "Dist (pixels): {}".format(cumul_dist_travelled), (15, 285), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35 , (0,0,0)) #retrieve frame number from cap and place in rectangle

        # Display inclusion status in the HUD
        if inclusion_status:
            text_color = (0, 0, 255) if inclusion_status == "Excluded" else (0, 255, 0)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'Inclusion Status: {inclusion_status}', (15, 310), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, text_color)
    
    return frame, blur, mask, eq

def output(frame, mask, eq, blur, mode="frame", inclusion_status=None, pause_on_excluded=False):
    """
    This function provides different ways of viewing the output of the tracked object
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    frame: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 3)
        source image with 3 colour channels
    blur: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        blurred image with 1 colour channel
    mask: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        binarised image with 1 colour channel 
    eq: ndarray, shape(n_rows, n_cols, 1)
        source image converted from colour to grey - 1 colour channel
    mode: str
        choose from 
            "frame" : shows tracked object in source image
            "mask" : shows tracked object in binarised mask image
            "blur" : shows tracked object in blurred image
            "frame+mask" : shows tracked object in source image and binarised mask image
            "frame_blur" : shows tracked object in source image and blurred image
            "blur+eq" : shows tracked object in blurred image and greyscale image
        different modes are useful when diagnosing problems with tracker
        inclusion_status: str or None
        Inclusion status for the frame ("Included" or "Excluded"). If None, no inclusion status is displayed.
    pause_on_excluded: bool
        If True, the function will pause for one second on excluded frames.
    """
    if mode == "frame":
        cv2.imshow('output', frame) 
    if mode == "mask":
        cv2.imshow('output', mask) 
    if mode == "blur":
        cv2.imshow('output', blur)
    if mode == "frame+mask":
        frame_plus_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
        hstack_frame_plus_mask = np.hstack((frame, frame_plus_mask))
        cv2.imshow("output", hstack_frame_plus_mask)
    if mode == "frame_blur":
        blur_2_colour = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hstack_frame_blur = np.hstack((frame, blur_2_colour))
        cv2.imshow('output', hstack_frame_blur)
    if mode == "blur+eq":
        hstack_gray_plus_eq = np.hstack((blur, eq))
        cv2.imshow("output", hstack_gray_plus_eq)

    if pause_on_excluded and inclusion_status == "Excluded":
        cv2.waitKey(100000) 


def frame_display_time(fps, mode = "slow_speed"):
    """
    This function provides ways of changing the speed of different images
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    fps: int
        The number of frames per second the output is displayed
    mode: str
        choose from
            "nat_speed" : natural filming speed of 25 frames per second (1000ms / 25frames = each frame displayed for 40ms)
            "veryfast_speed" :  each frame displayed for 2ms = 40ms/20
            "fast_speed" : each frame displayed for 4ms = 40ms/10
            "med_speed" : each frame displayed for 4ms = 8ms/5
            "slow_speed" : each frame dispayed for 200ms = 40ms*5
        useful for when wanting to speed up or slow down tracking process

    """
    nat_speed = int(1000/fps) 
    veryfast_speed = int((1000/fps)/40) 
    fast_speed = int((1000/fps)/10) 
    med_speed = int((1000/fps)/5) 
    slow_speed = int((1000/fps)*5)
    if mode == "nat_speed":
        key = cv2.waitKey(nat_speed) & 0xFF
    if mode == "veryfast_speed":
        key = cv2.waitKey(veryfast_speed) & 0xFF
    if mode == "fast_speed":
        key = cv2.waitKey(fast_speed) & 0xFF
    if mode == "med_speed":
        key = cv2.waitKey(med_speed) & 0xFF
    if mode == "slow_speed":
        key = cv2.waitKey(slow_speed) & 0xFF
    return key
```

I tried using chat GPT to modify the code. I've managed to add some things to make the script easier to use like the windows to designate the tracking arena and the individual area.

I'm realising I'm in over my head as I study biology and don't have any experience in coding apart from data analysis in R. I do realise the code is not that well written, it has been heavily modified using chat GPT by me and a different PhD student.

I would appreciate any help possible.